# Usage, Javac translation and runtime behavior of local classes

Tags: java

I occasionally use an implementation pattern (or idiom) where concrete implementations of an interface are encapsulated as a local class within factory methods and I'm interested in whether this is a bad or valid practice? How exactly does javac handle local classes? Are local classes lifted to top-level? IntelliJ unfortunately can't show me any bytecode for this. Furthermore I would be interested in the dynamics. Is there any negative impact for the runtime machinery (like dynamic class hierarchy analysis) and JIT compilation?

```
interface Transformer<A, B> extends Function<Iterable<A>, Iterable<B>> {

    @Override
    Iterable<B> apply(Iterable<A> itr);

    /// FACTORIES.

    /** Creates an transformer according to approach X. */
    static <A, B> Transformer<A, B> makeX(/* X specific params */) {
        final class TX implements Transformer<A, B> {
            @Override
            public Iterable<B> apply(Iterable<A> itr) {
                // ... X-style impl.
            }
        }
        return new TX();
    }

    /** Creates an transformer according to approach Y. */
    static <A, B> Transformer<A, B> makeY(/* Y specific params */) {
        final class TY implements Transformer<A, B> {
            @Override
            public Iterable<B> apply(Iterable<A> itr) {
                // ... Y-style impl.
            }
        }
        return new TY();
    }
}
```

Comment: AFAIK local classes are not lifted top level and they keep a reference to the parent class, so, in terms of performance itself, there's no difference between local classes and top level classes. However, the reference between the local (inner) classes and the parent class can be a problem regarding allocation/deallocation because of this extra reference.

Other than that, the most important thing here IMO is if your class organization makes sense, semantically, and if it's flexible enough for future changes in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Any form of nested class is compiled into a class with a mangled name. You can see these `.class` files after `javac` had done its business. Previously access to private members was done via default ("package") access, to make it fit the JDK1.0 model. More recently the JVM has acquired the concept of nesting.

The code examples are probably better off done as lambda functions. Even anonymous inner classes would be better as written.